# How we can remove duplicate elements from Nested List?

Tags: python

**this is nested list**

```
[['Dell', 2], ['Dell', 2], ['HP', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1]]
```

**Output Should be**

```
[['Dell', 2], ['HP', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1],]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your effort

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 1):

If the order doesn't matter:

```
lis = [['Dell', 2], ['Dell', 2], ['HP', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1]]
result = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, lis))))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through you list and add to other list if it is not already added.

```
data = [['Dell', 2], ['Dell', 2], ['HP', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1]]
new_data = []
for i in data:
  if i not in new_data:
    new_data.append(i)

print(new_data)
# Output [['Dell', 2], ['HP', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
before_remove = [['Dell', 2], ['Dell', 2], ['HP', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1], ['Sony', 5], ['Apple', 1]]
remove_duplicates = list(set(tuple(x) for x in before_remove))
```

if you want the nested items to be lists instead of tuples,

```
remove_duplicates = [list(y) for y in list(set(tuple(x) for x in before_remove))]
```